# Redirect all url start with /index.php?controller=allproducts to the home (with .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I used this rule, but nothing happen when visiting pages starting with that string.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php?controller=allproducts(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Query strings aren't considered to be a part of the URI, instead you need to use a condition search for the query string itself:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^controller=allproducts$
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R,L]
```

This would redirect http://website.com/index.php?controller=allproducts to http://website.com/index.php

Or if you're on Apache 2.4 you can use the [QSD] flag which discards the query. You would need to setup backreferences if you wanted to keep part of the query or use an absolute URL on the substitution if you wan't everything to go to the homepage.